# Widget is not responding on my custom refrence

Tags: magento, widget

i am trying to control a position on my view.pthml with a widget where i specified that a certain static_block only most show on certain products.

I have insert on my view.phtml: getChildHtml('right_product_promotion') ?>
I have created the right_product_promotion.phtml with some code 
getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('7')->toHtml(); ?>

I have insert on my page.xml : Right Product Promotion

i now can select the posistion "Right Product Promotion" on the widget block_reference when configure the widget...

so far so good, then i added to my catalog.xml:

and i have created a static block called "right_product_promotion" with the ID 7

Al well so far... the images are showing on my productview page, but it is showing them on every productpage and not on just the product i have select on configure the widget... where is it going wroing?

regards

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you've created a custom CMS block and not a widget. I suggest you follow the steps outlined here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-magento-widget-part-1
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-magento-widget-part-2